# Getting "No Certificates meet the Application Criteria" when trying to deploy to Windows Store

Tags: certificate, store

I've been publishing applications for years on the Windows Store.  I haven't deployed in about six months, so it's entirely possible that something may have expired.  When I try to select a certificate for my store application, I get this message:

[image]

I tried deleting the store association and re-associating.  Tried creating a self-signed certificate, and then downloading a cert from the store.  I tried creating a new product name and assigning it to a new Visual Studio UWP project.  Tried logging out and logging back in in Visual Studio to my Work account.  Checked the Partner's Center to see if some agreement had expired.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a certificate that just expired recently and now I'm seeing this issue as well, I've spent a couple hours trying different things but I haven't been able to get a new store certificate.

Comment: Yes. As I recall, it was some sort of project file corruption. I re-created my solution and all the projects in it with the latest version of VS 2022, then copied all the old code into the new projects (never copied a csproj or sln file), fixed a few of the project properties by hand, and everything worked.

Comment: Turns out I had to generate a test certificate and manually import it into the certificate store. Somehow doing that triggered VS to pull down a new store certificate during the release build. Seems like a bug in VS2019 where you need to have *some* certificate selected for it to build an app bundle, even if it's not the real store certificate (maybe this has been fixed in VS2022).